# Print words within the string from last to first

Tags: python, string

for example I entered follwoing string ;
" hello I am Mohsen" ;
now I want to Print on output :
"Mohsen am I hello "

please help me !

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: `' '.join(s.split()[::-1])`

Comment: Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Split by space, reverse the list, and stitch it back together.

```py
s = " hello I am Mohsen"
words = s.split(' ')
words_reversed = words[::-1]
s_reversed = ' '.join(words_reversed)

print(s_reversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Corralien's and Tobi208's works, and can be combined to the shorter version;

```
s = "hello I am Mohsen"   
print(' '.join(s.split(' ')[::-1]))
```

or if you want to input the string in the terminal as a prompt;

```
s = input()  
print(' '.join(s.split(' ')[::-1]))
```

Comment: Besides one liners, I thought it would be nice to have a solution that goes step by step for someone who's clearly new to the topic.